# Modulus of $|n^{-z}|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $\{a_n\} \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ be a bounded sequence, and let $\epsilon > 0$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n n^{-z}$ converges uniformly for $Re ~ z \ge 1 + \epsilon$. Here we choose the principal branch of $n^{-z}$.

Say $\{a_n\}$ is bounded by $C > 0$. I am reading a solution to this problem, but there is one step I don't understand:

> $$|a_n n^{-z}| \le C n^{-Re~z}$$

Is it true that $|n^{-z}| \le n^{- Re ~ z}$? How do you prove this? It would seem that it is equivalent to proving that $|n^{- Im~ z}| \le 1$, but I don't see how to prove this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|e^w| = e^{\operatorname{Re}(w)}$ holds for all complex numbers $w$, therefore
$$
|n^{-z}| = |e^{-z \log(n)}| = e^{\operatorname{Re}(-z \log(n))} = e^{- \operatorname{Re}(z)\log(n)} = n^{-\operatorname{Re}(z)}
$$
for $z \in \Bbb C$ and positive integers $n$.

Comment: .....D'oh! Thanks!